# Email Count in salesforce

Tags: reporting, email

I send a email to all my contacts, when customer open mail at that time report,html email status is showing number of opened--1 time, if customer is open more that 1 time at that situation the number is not updating may i know what i have to do

my images My Report

[image]

My Html Status

[image]

```
if customer open mail more than one time the mail at that situation also it showing     times of opened only 1..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email tracking system depends on a hidden image file embedded in the email. If this image file is cached (some clients cache downloaded assets), it will not show as being opened more than once. To test this, try opening the same email on more than one computer; it should show muliple "open" counts.

Comment: i am sending just text not more that .

Comment: i am not sending any imagefile in that mail, i am sending just text..

Comment: @Sathya Correct. When you send an HTML email, it includes a *hidden* image, supplied by the system.

Comment: how can i resolve my problem if same mail is open on same computer more than 1 time how count will be increment.

Comment: @Sathya It depends on the *recipient's* computer settings. You cannot bypass their computer settings.

Comment: i want to generate a report on leads to track the html status may i know it is possible..

Comment: @Sathya You can filter by template name, not by lead vs. contact. I don't have a better answer for you, unfortunately. Apparently the data isn't queryable, so you'd need a special built tool to get at this data.